# LSTM autoencoder - batch size larger than 1 causes ValueError

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, autoencoder

I am attempting to train an LSTM autoencoder on some `data` with shape `(21785, 160, 8)`. If I run the following code

```
import numpy as np

from keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, TimeDistributed
from keras import regularizers, models, optimizers
from keras.optimizers import Adam

data = np.random.random(size=(21785,160,8))

timesteps = 160
input_dim = 8 
latent_dim = 1

learning_rate = 1e-4
regularization = 5e-4
epochs=3

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(timesteps, input_dim))

encoded = layers.LSTM(latent_dim, activation='relu',
                    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(regularization))(inputs)

decoded = layers.RepeatVector(timesteps)(encoded)

decoded = layers.LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True, activation='relu',
                    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(regularization))(decoded)

sequence_autoencoder = keras.Model(inputs, decoded)
encoder = keras.Model(inputs, encoded)

encoder.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate), loss='mean_squared_error')
encoder.fit(data, data, epochs=epochs, batch_size=5, shuffle=False, verbose=True)
```

I get an error

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 5 and 160 for '{{node
> mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} =
> SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](model_3/lstm_2/strided_slice_3,
> IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [5,1], [5,160,8].

However, if I reduce the `batch_size = 1` then the code runs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: pay attention, you are fitting encoder while you need to fit sequence_autoencoder

Comment: How do I amend?